# TextInputLayout не работает стиль OutlinedBox

Tags: android, xml, android-style, textinputlayout

Возникла проблема при добавлении TextInputLayout делаю всё правильно но не могу понять в чём проблема т. к. добавляю стиль "Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox", но вокруг него не появляется обводки, а остаётся как обычно. Предоставляю код:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Имя пользователя"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Тема приложения (activity) какая?

Comment: Тему приложения изменить я не могу иначе много чего придется переписывать поэтому тему для TextInputLayout указываю через android:theme

Comment: Попробуйте указать тему у корневого элемента layout'а или хотя бы на уровень выше, чем TextInputLayout. Как-то так `<ConstraintLayout theme="MaterialComponents"><TextInputLayout><TextInputEditText/></TextInputLayout></ConstraintLayout>` Тема не срабатывает на сам элемент, одновременно с указанием стиля из этой темы (вероятно).

Comment: Вы были правы я понятие как это должно работать но оно работает спасибо вам!